# where is boost make_seconds?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

Nice day to all!

I try to compile a little example from boost docs pdf's:

```
#include "boost/icl/interval.hpp"
#include "boost/icl/interval_set.hpp"
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_duration.hpp"
#include <boost/icl/ptime.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::icl;
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;
...
interval<boost::posix_time::seconds>::type news(seconds(), make_seconds("20:15:00"));
interval<seconds>::type talk_show(make_seconds("22:45:30"), make_seconds("23:30:50"));
interval_set<seconds> myTvProgram;
myTvProgram.add(news).add(talk_show);
// Iterating over elements (seconds) would be silly ...
for(interval_set<seconds>::iterator telecast = myTvProgram.begin();
telecast != myTvProgram.end(); ++telecast)
//...so this iterates over
return 0;
```

I've error: 
error C3861: 'make_seconds': identifier not found

How to make correct convert? Thanks.

Comment: Grep-ing the boost directory of version 1.49 shows only the documentation references. Perhaps this is a mistake in the documentation. I would ask on the boost mailing list.

Comment: it could be deprecated... boost evolves... this might not be the case here, but if you are in a  hurry you could try to guestimate which version of boost was active when guide was written.

Comment: I've downloaded latest 1.51 both boost and pdf doc's